# Passing specific type as generic for function overloading

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to figure out how to get an overloaded method based on generic type passed as parameter on the method.

The following code will explain what I want to achieve.

```
public class GetUser{
    public User Execute<T>(int userId) where T : User { return null; }

    public UserModel Execute<T>(int userId) where T : Business { return null; }
}

(new GetUser()).Execute<User>(1);
(new GetUser()).Execute<UserModel>(2);
```

The problem on that approach, since it still pass same parameter the 
visual studio still shows that the Execute method is already defined.

If I do this

```
 public User Execute<T>(this User obj, int userId) where T : User { return null; }
```

the visual studio still ask for the first parameter to pass.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please describe what is wrong with your code

Comment: Generic type constraint is not a part of the method signature.

Comment: You cannot have overloads wich only differ in return types.

Comment: How are you going to use `T` in your methods?

Answer (score 2):

This is **not possible**.

Overloaded method must be dependend on method parameters, not only on return type or generic parameter.